# how to access angular $scope from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have added a functionality to parse a CSV file in javascript. I want to assign the parsed data to $scope.data.arr. Currently, the below code gives error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: scope is not defined**". I am newbie to AngularJS and I have followed the official angular tutorials.

The code is:

**application.js**

```
'use strict';
/* Application module */
var ddvApp = angular.module('ddvApp', ['ddvControllers']);
```

**dataController.js**

```
'use strict';
/*Data Controller*/

var ddvControllers = angular.module('ddvControllers', []);

ddvControllers.controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {}; //created a empty data object.
}]);
```

**read-csv.js**

```
function handleFiles(files) {
  // Check for the various File API support.
  if (window.FileReader) {
    // FileReader are supported.
    getAsText(files[0]);
  } 
  else {
    alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
  }
}

function getAsText(fileToRead) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
  reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
  // Handle errors load
  reader.onload = loadHandler;
  reader.onerror = errorHandler;
}

function loadHandler(event) {
  var csv = event.target.result;
  scope.data.arr = processData(csv); //this is the line of code where i want to assign the parsed data to the angularjs $scope.
}

function processData(csv) {
  var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var lines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    var arr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      arr.push(data[j].trim());
    }
    lines.push(arr);
  }
  return lines;
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  if(event.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
    alert("Cannot read file !");
  }
}
```

--UPDATE Problem Statement.

The handleFiles() function is called whenever user selects a new csv file to be parsed.

html code:

```
<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" accept=".csv">
```

I firstly implemented the code to parse the CSV in javascript. I am using this data to render a graph on html canvas. I wanted a functionality where the user just selects a different csv file with updated data and the graph should update itself without further inputs. I added angularjs because (in future implementations) the file and graph need to be saved to a db. Also, some data can be requested from server instead of user loading it using a csv file.

Comment: Why do you expect `scope.data.arr` to be available there? When/where is your `read-csv` code being executed? Why aren't you doing it in an angular service/factory?

Comment: Will update my question will all other details.

Comment: Restructure your code. Don't put your `read-csv` code into the global scope - put it in an Angular **service**. In your controller, you can inject the service and then bind an `onchange` event to the `input`. In that handler, call the new service method, passing the input's `files`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can get acccess to the `$scope` via angular's `element()` function it looks like this is code that would be better put into an angular `service`.

If doing that is for some reason not an option, you need a reference to a DOM element that belongs to your `controller`.

Once you have that, you can do

```
angular.element(myDomElement).scope()
```

and that should give you a reference.

You can also use `element.find()` with css selectors but be aware that if you have not loaded `JQuery` you're left with a limited set of selectors (tag-names only).

See [Docs for angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score -1):

What should be done is to copy all the JavaScript from read-csv.js and put it into dataController.js below this line:

```
$scope.data = {}; //created a empty data object.
```

define arr as an array:

```
$scope.data = {
  arr: []
};
```

add a '$' in front of scope so that line should be:

```
$scope.data.arr = processData(csv);
```

This should fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to do this is to put the functions in your read-csv.js file into a service, and then handle events using $rootScope.broadcast and $scope.$on.

So it may look something like:

```
module.factory('readCsv' ['$rootScope', function(rootScope){
    var readCsv = {};
    // load readCsv with read-csv.js functions
    readCsv.loadHandler = function(event){
        var csv = readCsv.processData(event.target.result);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('$csvEvent', csv);
    };
    return readCsv;

}]).controller('DataController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.$on('$csvEvent', function(csv){
        $scope.data.arr = csv;
    };
}]);
```